# Comportamiento inesperado con bindings

Tags: python, tkinter

Mi widget `wg` tiene los siguientes bindings:

```
self.wg.bind("<Enter>", self._on_enter)
self.wg.bind("<Leave>", self._on_leave)
self.wg.bind("<FocusIn>", self._on_focus)
self.wg.bind("<FocusOut>", self._on_leave_focus)
```

Y aquí las funciones que llaman los bindings:

```
def _on_enter(self, e):
    if not self._in:
        self.wg.config(highlightbackground = "black")

def _on_leave(self, e):
    if not self._in:
        self.wg.config(highlightbackground = "#7a7a7a")

def _on_focus(self, e):
    self.wg.config(highlightbackground = "red")
    self._in = True

def _on_leave_focus(self, e):
    self.wg.config(highlightbackground= "#7a7a7a")
    self._in = False
```

(`self._in` por defecto es `True`, lo uso para que no ocurran cambios si el puntero entra o sale mientras se tenga el teclado enfocado en el widget).

El comportamiento que esperaba era que al pasar el mouse encima, el color del borde (highlight) sea negro, y cuando salga, se vuelva gris. Esto **funciona correctamente**. Lo que no funciona son los bindings **FocusIn** y **FocusOut**, dado que esperaría que cuando el teclado está en el widget correspondiente, el borde pase a color rojo, y cuando sale, regrese al gris; esto no ocurre, se queda del mismo gris, no importa si salgo haciendo click en otro widget o presionando Tab. ¿Me estoy equivocando al entender los bindings?

[La documentación](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) dice:

> **FocusIn**
>
> El foco del teclado se movió a este widget, o a un hijo de este widget.

¿Por qué entonces no funciona como se espera?

Comment: Hola Danny, ¿que widget es en concreto? ¿Derivas directamente de Widget? ¿o es un Entry, etc?

Comment: Es el TextWithVar que comentaste en otra de mis preguntas :P osea es un derivado de `tk.Text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no es el evento, es el atributo que intentas cambiar:

- **`highlightbackground`**: es el color de resaltado del borde  cuando el widget **no tiene el foco**.
- **`highlightcolor`**: es el color de resaltado del borde  cuando el widget **tiene el foco**.

En tu caso, cuando el widget gana el foco (cursor en él) se aplica `highlightcolor`, no `highlightbackground`, por lo que de rojo, ni rastro.

```
import tkinter as tk


class TextWithVar(tk.Text):
    '''A text widget that accepts a 'textvariable' option'''
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, textvariable=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self._textvariable = textvariable
        self._on_var_change()

        self.tk.eval('''
            proc widget_proxy {widget widget_command args} {

                # call the real tk widget command with the real args
                set result [uplevel [linsert $args 0 $widget_command]]

                # if the contents changed, generate an event we can bind to
                if {([lindex $args 0] in {insert replace delete})} {
                    event generate $widget <<Change>> -when tail
                }
                # return the result from the real widget command
                return $result
            }
            ''')

        self.tk.eval(f'''
            rename {self} _{self}
            interp alias {{}} ::{self} {{}} widget_proxy {self} _{self}
        ''')

        self.bind("<<Change>>", self._on_widget_change)

        if self._textvariable is not None:
            self._textvariable.trace_add(("write", "unset"), self._on_var_change)

    def _on_var_change(self, *args):
        '''Change the text widget when the associated textvariable changes'''
        text_current = self.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        var_current = self._textvariable.get()
        if text_current != var_current:
            self.delete("1.0", "end")
            self.insert("1.0", var_current)

    def _on_widget_change(self, event=None):
        '''Change the variable when the widget changes'''
        if self._textvariable is not None:
            self._textvariable.set(self.get("1.0", "end-1c"))


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent,  *args, **kwargs)
        self.var = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.wg = TextWithVar(self, textvariable=self.var)
        self.wg.pack()

        self.wg.bind("<Enter>", self._on_enter)
        self.wg.bind("<Leave>", self._on_leave)

        self.wg.config(highlightcolor = "red")
        tk.Entry(self).pack()


    def _on_enter(self, e):
        self.wg.config(highlightbackground = "black")

    def _on_leave(self, e):
        self.wg.config(highlightbackground = "#7a7a7a")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ... Ni siquiera se me había ocurrido que no era el highlight!!! Perfecto, gracias